# jquery mobile border-left not rendering for some input types

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-mobile

Please refer to the following fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/davidxn/gx9fZ/2/

I've created CSS:

```
textarea.required {
  border-left: 1px solid red;   
}
```

That *should* render like the second text area, but it doesn't. Same happens for a select, but an input of type="text" is ok. Note how the border-left is ok for the second textarea (probably because of the explicit style attribute).

I'd rather be able to do this through CSS. Is there a way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove all css and try this:

```
.required {
  border-left: 1px solid red !important;    
}
```

Comment: I'm curious to know why adding select to the selector doesn't work, i.e.:

select.required {
  border-left: 1px solid red !important;    
}

But just for selects. Works for textarea

Comment: It may be because, JQUERY itself is having some styles for different HTML object. So if we are just specifying some styles, the default style will be overriding the user-defined one.

Answer (score 0):

It is happening because of the dynamic classes have the same border property and that overwriting your border style. So add `!important` keyword to your classes. It will work. By the way why you write each end every tag  `required` classes separately. You can combine everything into single one like below.

```
.required
{
 border-left:1px solid red !important;
}
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/gx9fZ/3/)